# F# Error and Mergesort

Tags: algorithm, recursion, merge, f#

I'm writing a mergesort function in F#, but I am receiving this error code and I don't understand why.

"error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
val it : '_a list when '_a : comparison 
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation."

I get the error code when I try calling, for example, mergesort [1; 2; 3; 3; 2; 6];;

Here is the code snippet

```
let rec merge l =
  match l with
  | ([], ys) -> ys
  | (xs, []) -> xs
  | (x::xs, y::ys) -> if x < y then x :: merge (xs, y::ys)
                      else y :: merge (x::xs, ys)

let rec split l =
  match l with
  | [] -> ([], [])
  | [a] -> ([a], [])
  | a::b::cs -> let (M,N) = split cs
                (a::M, b::N)

let rec mergesort l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | L -> let (M, N) = split L
         merge (mergesort M, mergesort N)
```

Comment: For me the code compiles fine although there seems to be a slight mistake in `mergesort` causing stackoverflow. By fixing it one seem to fix the FSI problem. FSI occassionally reports the wrong error, seems like it's one of those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the code in VS2015. The error reproduces in FSI but if I run it as a program the program crashes with `StackOverflowException`.

Turns out there's a slight mistake in `mergesort`

```
let rec mergesort l =
  match l with
  | [] 
  | [_] -> l // Without this case mergesort crashes with `StackOverflowException`
  | L -> let (M, N) = split L
    merge (mergesort M, mergesort N)
```

Fixing this error fixed it for me in FSI. I have noticed that occassionally FSI shows the wrong error message. Seems to be one of those cases.

Comment: Ahh, why is there a discrepancy between FSI and VS2015?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help tho